# esp32 calling a FREERTOS task from void loop

Tags: esp32, freertos

I need some help.

I create a FREERTOS vtask "void Mytask(*pvPerameters)" which works fine. Than within a void x() I create an if statement  if(ledstate !=1) Mytask();

My problem is the compiler complains of the if statement " no enough arguments for Mytask().

In my project I want to run a wifi.scannetwork which seems to hang all other functions for a few seconds. My thoughts are, if I run this as a vtask on a seperate core it should keep the rest running without a delay. Ive read that all wifi functions run on core 1 but I still get a slow response from a web page during the time I call wifican. not sure if its because wifi cant do both server and scan at the same time?

I remove "Mytask" from FREERTOS and it all works fine. What am I missing

Comment: I’d recommend reading a tutorial or two on FreeRTOS; you don’t use tasks by calling them.

Comment: can't it be done with handle suspend and resume?

Comment: Don’t abuse suspend/resume for task synchronization. Better use semaphore, notification or a queue.

Comment: You showed code that directly called the task function. It doesn’t work that way. If that’s not the code you’re asking about then edit the question and provide the actual code.